# Syntax highlighting and code inspection in CLion stops working after including anything from standard library

Tags: c++, ide, clion

The problem started happening after upgrading GCC to version 10 on Ubuntu 20.04.Basically my code gets highlighted and inspected fine until I include a standard library header (string for example). Sometimes when I remove the include line the highlighting comes back and sometimes it comes back only if I restart CLion after removing the line. The code compiles fine. I already tried reinstalling GCC, CLion and whole Ubuntu and the problem is exactly the same. The problem is not consistent for all the headers because cstdint works fine and doesn't break anything but string, map and iostream do. I don't have any external plugins, it's a totally fresh install of the newest CLion and Ubuntu. Going back to GCC-9 fixes the problem, but GCC-10 just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you used C++20? If so it seems it's your problem https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-20238